# Выбрать используемый ssh ключ

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh-key

Есть ssh ключ `~/.ssh/openshift_id`.

Как научить *intellij idea* использовать его, а не `~/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Comment: Idea скорее всего и не использует никакие ключи, предоставляя эту задачу ssh. Создайте файл `~.ssh/config`:

    Host example
        Hostname example.com
        IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/openshift_id
        User xxxx
        Port xxxx

Любые из вышеперечисленных полей необязательны, насколько помню, указание Host example.com и IdentityFile будет достаточно

И не забудьте поставить права 600 на приватный ключ и 700 на .ssh

Comment: Только не Hostname, а HostName, насколько помню, это важно.

Comment: @Etki ниважна )

Answer (score 2):

вероятно, программа *inetlij-idea* не «занимается» ключами.

вам надо сконфиругировать нужным образом клиента *ssh*.

для этого добавьте в `~/.ssh/config` две строки:

```
host имя-или-ip-адрес
identityfile ~/.ssh/openshift_id
```

где `имя-или-ip-адрес` ­— имя или ip-адрес хоста, при подключении к которому надо использовать данный ключ. например, `github.com`.

и не забудьте убрать любой доступ всем кроме вас к каталогу `~/.ssh` и его содержимому:

```
$ chmod -R go= ~/.ssh
```